# Trouble in Calculating Force required to pull a chain over an inclined Plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

**Question:-** A uniform chain of length $l$ and mass $m$ is hanging vertically at edge of an inclined plane AB of length $l$ which is making an angle of $30$ degrees with horizontal. Find  work done in pulling Chain slowly to AB.

[image]

Using concept of centre of mass and gravitational potential energy I was able to find work done as $\frac {3mgl}{4}$

I also tried to find total work done by calculating differential work done and then integrating it over desired limits.

$$W=\int dw=\int Fdx$$

[image]

According to me $$F=\frac{mgx}{l}+\frac {mg(l-x)}{2l}$$

But after integrating it over limits $-l$ to $0$. I got wrong answer.

How can I calculate correct value of $F$. Also can somebody tell me what is the significance of pulling chain slowly.

Comment: @Why are you reading my name That means Chain is pulled with constant velocity. I think that this is required because we have to write change in kinetic energy as well with change in potential energy in work equation.

Comment: Also To write change in kinetic energy we should be given acceleration with which chain is pulled. In that case $F_{net}$ won't be $0$.

Comment: @ user1000, the significance of 'pulling the chain slowly' is that the system is moving quasistatically. That's a fancy way of saying that is covering very small  distances in long periods of time. So there is little to no velocity of chain. So if you can apply Work-Energy Theorem, you have to take change in kinetic energy as zero. This is primarily because kinetic energy of chain approaches zero since velocity approaches zero.

Comment: @Why are you reading my name You were correct. $F$ was calculated wrong because I have taken mistakenly sine of 30 degrees as $\frac {√3}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An infinitesimal mass element can be written as

\begin{equation}
dm=\rho dx
\end{equation}

where $\rho$ is the density, assumed to be constant. This means that a finite mass is obtained by multiplying the density with a finite length.

The total work is given by a sum of two contributions. First, we have to consider when the chain is vertical, and second, when it lies along the incline. Moreover, if a piece with length $x$ is on the incline, then obviously the other piece has length $l-x$. I also assume that there is no friction.

The works are then
\begin{equation}
W_1=\int_0^{l}dx\,\rho(l-x)g=\frac{\rho gl^2}{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
W_2=\int_0^{l}dx\, \rho x  g\sin\theta =\frac{\rho gl^2}{4}
\end{equation}

The total work done is then

\begin{equation}
W=W_1+W_2=\frac{3}{4}\rho l^2=\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{m}{l}\right)l^2=\frac{3}{4}mlg
\end{equation}

We move the chain slowly so that we can neglect possible deformations and internal stresses that could arise during the journey. In that case, the density would be a function of $x$, $\rho(x)$ so the result would obviously change.